# boost asio use_future completion token thread-safety

Tags: c++, boost-asio

When performing the following piece of code

```cpp
boost::asio::socket s{...};

auto f1 = s.async_read(..., boost::asio::use_future);
auto f2 = s.async_write(..., boost::asio::use_future);
```

given that with `use_future` we do not really specify the context, of where the promise will be set with result value - does this mean that 2 tasks could be running in different threads? and there is no guarantee on single-threadness(use must ensure thread-safety) here?

thanks!

Comment: I am confused about the question. The context is specified in the constructor of the socket `s`.

Comment: although context is specified in the ctor, it is possible to construct another executor from the token, afaik

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says, the executor of the IO object (`s`) will be used for the completion. So all the guarantees of that executor apply.

If you have an execution context that is being polled (`run` or `poll`) from a single thread, that thread will be definition set the value or exception on the promise associated with the returned future. Interestingly, it doesn't really matter as `std::future` is already thread safe and the internal `promise` isn't shared.

With regards to having two asynchronous operations in flight, that has nothing to do with the completion token. The restrictions documented for the IO object apply. In the case of sockets at most one read and one write operation are allowed to be in flight at any given moment.

Comment: the reason for the question is that it is possible to construct an executor from the provided completion token (use_future here) and not use execution context specified in the constructor. I understand that this is not the case for socket impl, but in general, it is possible that such a thing happens (for another impl of something...). https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp20/operations/callback_wrapper.cpp

Comment: It is *not* possible to construct an executor from `asio::use_future`. It **is** possible to have a completion token bound with _an associated executor_, e.g. one wrapped on a strand. `asio::use_future` does not have that. The fallback depends on context: for operations involving IO objects, the bound executor thereof will be taken, otherwise `system_executor` will be used, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52460852/85371) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66733239/85371)

Comment: I guess I did not phrase correctly - indeed, __not construct__ but rather somehow obtain one... and the default behavior is probably what I was after...

Comment: Yes. You can verify the default being `system_executor` indirectly: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/546776fe96d4ab22