# start a coroutine immediately C++ asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

When using pre-coroutine asio interface I could dispatch an async function in the current execution context (main function) and let it finish in the `ctx`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace literals;

int main() {
    asio::io_context ctx;
    asio::steady_timer t(ctx, 2s);
    asio::dispatch([&](){
        cout << "inside coro before wait" << endl;
        t.async_wait([](asio::error_code){
            cout << "inside coro after wait" << endl;
        });
    });
    cout << "starting ctx.run()" << endl;
    ctx.run();
}
```

```
$ ./sol
inside coro before wait
starting ctx.run()
inside coro after wait
```

I would like to replicate this with `asio::awaitable` but `dispatch` doesn't support coroutines.

On the other hand `co_spawn` only adds the coroutine to the context, and doesn't initiate it immediately.

I could use `ctx.poll()`/`ctx.run_one()` but the coroutine would have to be the only one ready to execute or at least the first one.

**Anwser**

If I'm not mistaken the only way to start a coroutine (from outside of coroutine) is using [`asio::co_spawn(executor, awaitable, token)`](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.26.0/doc/asio/reference/co_spawn.html). In contrast to `dispatch`, `co_spawn` takes an executor as an argument, where as @sehe said `dispatch` uses [associated executor](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.26.0/doc/asio/overview/model/associators.html). So to answer my question on how to start a coroutine immediately is to run it in `asio::system_executor()`.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <asio.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace literals;

int main() {
    asio::io_context ctx;
    asio::co_spawn(asio::system_executor(), [&]() -> asio::awaitable<void> {
        cout << "inside coro before wait" << endl;
        asio::steady_timer t(ctx, 2s);
        co_await t.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable);
        cout << "inside coro after wait" << endl;
        co_return;
    }, asio::detached);
    cout << "starting ctx.run()" << endl;
    ctx.run();
}
```

```
$ ./sol
inside coro before wait
starting ctx.run()
inside coro after wait
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a myriad ways in which this code won't do what it suggests/you describe it will do:

```
asio::dispatch([](){
    // executes immediately
    asio::steady_timer t(ctx, 2s);
    t.async_wait([](){
        // executes in ctx.run()
    });
});
ctx.run();
```

- It will **never** wait 2s, because `t`'s destructor will cancel the `async_await` **immediately** after being initiated.
- `ctx` is apparently a static or a global, because it isn't captured
- the completion handler doesn't have the required signature
- even if it did correctly accept an `error_code` variable, it would **not** *"execute[s] in ctx.run()"* because the `dispatch` dispatches on the [associated executor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/associators.html) of the lambda. This, because nothing else is associated, will default to a default-constructed instance of `asio::system_executor`.

  > See e.g. [Which io_context does std::boost::asio::post / dispatch use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52458609/which-io-context-does-stdboostasiopost-dispatch-use/52460852#52460852)

> **Q.** *On the other hand asio::co_spawn only adds the coroutine to the context, and doesn't initiate it immediately.*

I don't think that's accurate either. As you mention the code you give is invalid (because `post` doesn't support coroutines). When fixed to use `co_spawn`, we can show it to run inside `ctx.run()`:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    asio::io_context ctx;
    asio::co_spawn(
        ctx,
        []() -> asio::awaitable<void> {
            auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
            asio::steady_timer t(ex, 2s);
            co_await t.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable);
            std::cout << "inside ctx.run()" << std::endl;
            // co_return;
        },
        asio::detached);

    std::cout << "before ctx.run()" << std::endl;
    ctx.run();
    std::cout << "after ctx.run()" << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

[image]

I really think 99% of the question hinges on these false premises, so I'll await your reaction before expounding.

### UPDATE

Thinking longer I think you might be having a variation on this question: [asio How to change the executor inside an awaitable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987021/asio-how-to-change-the-executor-inside-an-awaitable/71991876#71991876), but without realizing that you had unwittingly been using the system context for the dispatch.

Here's [a more comprehensive illustration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a10e41ea2b97b403) of precisely how (associated) executors interact with coroutine resume: [full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TcxA.jpg)

[image]

> *NOTE also how the work guard is required to avoid ctx running out of work while work is only pending on the system context.*

I strongly recommend against relying on the system context, but this illustration should help you connect all the dots?

Comment: Thinking longer I think you might be having a variation on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987021/asio-how-to-change-the-executor-inside-an-awaitable/71991876#71991876), but without realizing that you had unwittingly been using the system context for the dispatch.

Comment: Here's a more comprehensive illustration of precisely how (associated) executors interact with coroutine resume: https://imgur.com/a/cwCWq0n - note also how the work guard is required to avoid `ctx` running out of work while work is **only** pending on the system context. I strongly recommend against relying on the system context, but this illustration should help you connect all the dots?

Comment: What I actually wanted is to change the execution context of the awaitable and start it in the system_executor, thank you for clarifying things